Clonezilla 'dry-run' or 'what-if' mode to calculate final image size
Is there an option for clonezilla to make it calculate the final image size of a disk to image without actually creating the image, like a test mode or what-if switch?
I've searched and read docs haven't come across a way but hoping that's because it's underground black art cli-fu that isn't documented but can be done.
